# How do I echo same character till the end of line

Tags: shell, echo

I want to echo character "=" till the end of line independent of the size of terminal window for a shell script

I can just do this:

```
echo -e "\e[1;35;40m =======================================================================================\e[0m"
```

But It is just a random line. I want the character to repeat till the end of line has reached. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in $(seq 1 $(stty size | cut -d' ' -f2)); do 
  echo -n "=" 
done
```